# Why don't we have instant messaging on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, private-messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

I don't expect that this is going to go over well here based on the only other [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/how-user-messaging-could-be-realized) I've found related to this topic, but here goes....

It seems that some sort of user-to-user messaging is the only major "social/community" feature missing from Stack Exchange. Would there be any value to adding user-to-user messaging outside of the context of questions, answers and comments?

What are the reasons for and against including user-to-user messaging on SE sites? Note that the lack of the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag is intentional. I'm not requesting that the feature be added. I'm just interested in the discussion about it.

Comment: Have you looked at Facebook? If so, why do you want to turn the nice, clean, simple, purpose-driven SO sites into the site you use as an example of pointless featuritis?

Comment: random updated their status: "What? No votes left? Back in 11 hours?"

Comment: I didn't tag this a feature-request on purpose.  I wasn't requesting the feature be added, I'm just interested in the discussion about it.

Answer (score 17):

The big reason against: SO *isn't* a social networking site. It's a Q&A site. Anything which distracts from making it as simple as possible to ask questions and answer them is taking away from the main point, IMO.

To put it another way: do you expect Windows Live Messenger or Google Talk to add Q&A features? If not, why not?

Comment: why not allow it, but add the possibility of opting out? It doesn't have to be a facebook or google chat, but sometimes it would be useful to be able to talk to someone.

Comment: @Vivi, even if you make it opt- _in_, just having the option available will make the site more "social networky" in users' heads, especially new users.

Comment: @Popular Demand: but isn't chat making it more "social networky" anyway?

Comment: @Vivi, unfortunately, it is. But one step in the wrong direction doesn't justify a second step in the wrong direction. Chat has been useful for a few things, but overall, the reward-to-effort ratio just isn't there.

Answer (score 7):

It's not missing.

It's not wanted.

Comment: Given the fact that this is a very common request, I dispute the notion that it's not wanted.

Comment: Common request or good way to test the patience of dupe and search features? U decide!

Comment: Technically, repeated expressions of (dis)interest in something (from different parties) are not dupes, because the information is the volume of desire.  On the other hand, non-new arguments why something is a good or bad idea often are duplicates, because the information is the argument.

Answer (score 6):

Users can include IM details in their profiles if they are interested in being contacted that way.  Jeff Atwood is pretty adamant about SO, etc. not being a social networking site, but rather a place to get answers for questions.

Answer (score 3):

This has been covered pretty bluntly by the many attempts to water a first-rate Q&A site down into some sort of social forum.

[StackOverflow Software Stack as Social Networking Tool?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/stackoverflow-software-stack-as-social-networking-tool)

[Is it wrong for the community to add ‘social’ features using scripts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/stackoverflow-software-stack-as-social-networking-tool)

[Private Message Feature [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/private-message-feature-closed)