# Maybe we have other things to talk about apart from programming?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, private-messaging

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Private Message Feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/private-message-feature)
>   [instant messaging on SO SF SU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/instant-messaging-on-so-sf-su)

The whole question & answer concept has proved itself, but why don't you support something like private messages?

Or an alternative forum to ask some off-topic discussion questions? (For which you don't get points if it bothers you.)

(As far as I understand it, you can't ask in Meta things like, "What's your favorite animal?")

Comment: We all like Ponies here.

Comment: @Daniel May: I don't like ponies, I'm just upvoting them.

Comment: Dupe of a dupe of a... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/private-message-

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17951/why-not-a-pm-system-closed

See me answer to that link.

Answer (score 2):

Offtopics (like what's your favorite animal) shouldn't be asked in a programming site, like SO, even if there's some more private room, like the upcoming chat feature.

There's a StackExchange site that's dedicated to talk about offtopics, which aren't covered in any other StackExchange site, which is [Offtopic](http://offtopic.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What upcoming chat feature? Have I missed something here?

Comment: I don't remember which question was answered by a link in which Jeff  talks about planed new features in the site. You can search here for questions about the new features.

Answer (score 1):

Other sites exist for other topics. I don't ask theology questions here, I go to a theology forum. I don't drum up a community, or chat in general about the forum software project I work with, we have a forum for that.

Everything has a place, and programming has StackOverflow, Server Admin has ServerFault, and Super Users have SuperUser. Questions/problems/etc. with the engine itself have Meta.

If you want to chat with people, post a link in your profile to where you like to hang. If it doesn't exist, make it. If you don't know how to make it - well, there's a programming question. ;)