# Recommended place to settle disputes?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that there isn't a PM system on Stack Overflow [for various reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17951/why-not-a-pm-system).

However, I have a dispute with another user who keeps bugging me about it on SO. I want to move that discussion to another place to get this bad karma away from Stack Overflow, however I also don't want to give this guy my PM information because I don't like him and don't trust him.

Can anyone recommend a suitable place, open or private (preferably open), inside or outside SO (preferably inside), where I can open up a discussion with this guy?

Another option is to ignore him and report him (again) to the ops when he crosses the line, but I want to at least consider a discussion with him too.

Comment: Do you mean the user you had a longer quarrel with on SO? That guy is a total psycho. I don't think anything can be gained from discussing with him. If at all possible, I would just ignore him

Comment: I think he has a narcistic disorder of some kind, yes. I am definitely considering ignoring him, I'm just not that good at controlling my impulses ;)

Comment: @littlegreen yeah, but I think it would be the best option. IIRC. there have been several discussions about his behaviour on Meta already, as you can see to no avail. (I'm softening my comment a bit)

Comment: It's just that I don't like writing people off. I would prefer a discussion, but I agree that in his case it would probably not make a difference.

Comment: Hey, I recognize your picture, didn't you have a different name before? Pekka or something?

Comment: @littlegreen That's Pekka alright, but ever since `<kbd>` came back the Meta crowd's got excited, [for some reason...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive)

Comment: @YiJiang is correct. And now I'm stuck with it for 30 days :)

Comment: @Rejoice What happened to [your favorite bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54986/name-change-limiting-can-be-broken/55942#55942)? Sure, it's clunkier now but you're already named Pekka everywhere else.

Comment: @Grace true, but that would overwrite all the other profiles, and I have custom text in some. Too lazy to deal with that right now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is now open to all, and should be suitable for this - it is both open (transcript is available to all to see) and inside the Stack Overflow system. You can [open up a room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new) and invite that user - the other user will see the notification on the Stack Exchange SuperColliding Dropdown global inbox.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Stack Exchange SuperColliding Dropdown Global Inbox.

Comment: +1, but the last time we tried this, it didn't work. Of course, that user turned out to be a troll, so... classic your-mileage-may-vary situation, I guess.

Comment: It wasn't by any chance the same user, was it?

Comment: @littlegreen, I have no idea which user is giving you grief, but the one I'm thinking of was banned. If yours was active in the last few months, it's not the same guy.

Comment: Well his name was troll3rz666 and he really made me angry.. where can i file a complaint??! (just kidding, it wasn't the same user)

Comment: Well, that was a disappointment. The user in question feels himself a "Professional" and "Professionals" do not spend their time on "Chat". He suggests emailing him, but I still don't trust him with that, and I changed my opinion; this is a problem between him and the community, not a problem between me and him. He **wants** it to be a problem between me and him, because then he can just pretend the problem is me. But it isn't, I'm just currently the only fool who doesn't shut up about it ;)