# Is there plans for an IM Capability?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [instant messaging on SO SF SU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/instant-messaging-on-so-sf-su)

I have just had the experience of asking a question on server fault. I then was informed that it belonged on superuser. So I deleted the question and asked it there. Now a fellow who was educating me about correct usage of these forums i.e. the correct place to ask, different types of questions, then came over to superuser where I added the question and left a comment, which was directly related to my use of the system and not the question itself, thus detracting from the question, NOISE if you will.  Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the comment but I felt it would have been better if the user could have clicked an icon next to my display name and it say, send this user a message.

Is it more that this would introduce hidden solutions and then this facility would detract from the intended usage of the site?

Comment: No. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/instant-messaging-on-so-sf-su
and also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: FWIW, if you want to discuss the meta aspects of a specific question, you can ask about it on this site.

Comment: Actually FWIW he did.

Comment: @EBGreen: Ah, so he did. Skipped over that one 'cause i didn't understand the title - retitled, retagged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is supposed to be out in the open for everyone to see on S[OFU]. Now anyone else that reads that question on SU will potentially get the education too.

Answer (score 8):

IM is death for StackOverflow. I can't imagine how many people will ask various questions, small and big, by IMing Jon, Marc, etc. and believe me, it will be very irritating.

Comment: This assumes IM would allow anybody to contact anybody. Certainly, if IM were implemented it would work on friend-lists that would require you to accept a friend before they could contact you.

Comment: In that case, if you're Jon, for instance, everybody would send you a friend request and (1) if you accept, you'll get bothered by questions. (2) if you don't, people might think you're too arrogant.

Comment: @Jonathan: I would reject you all. Well, the three of you who would try to friend me.

Comment: Unless the IM capability is opt-in, that way when you look for Jon you get a "Jon is not subscribed to IM service". In any case I'm opposed to the idea as well, just mentioning a possible way out of that conundrum. Waffles!

Answer (score 5):

## No. Please, no.