# How to handle link rot and broken links?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, broken-link

Some questions and answers on stackoverfow have broken links. And sometimes it is important links in accepted or most upvoted answers.

If the question is old, and I have no idea of what the link should be pointing to, how can I  tell the author to try to fix it?

In my case, I am refering to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413661/php6-is-short-open-tag-removed-or-deprecated-or-neither/2413675#2413675) and the link "this entry" in the accepted answer.

Comment: Add a comment to the post indicating that the link is broken. The poster will be notified the next time they log on (like you will be notified of this comment).

Comment: That question is from that Pekka guy.  He's pretty unreliable, he went on vacation one day and never came back. ;)

Comment: @Jonsca: At least here on Meta...some other guy calling himself a Troll took his place...on the other hand that guy vanished, too, and I see a very odd ice-cream man very often in the last time...wonder what's up with that...

Comment: The answer to the question is from him, I meant, not the question. Oops.

Comment: See also [Can we have some tools to handle link rot?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71529)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The action to be taken depends, but your options are:

- Leave a comment, explaining that the link is broken.
- Edit the answer yourself, replacing the link with a working one.
- Flag for moderator attention or as `Not an answer` if it only consists of one link.

***But*** the last option is only available for *0-votes not-accepted low-quality answers* <sup>tm</sup>. Otherwise poke (read: comment) the user, or fix it yourself.

Comment: Worth noting that posts that consist almost _entirely_ of a broken (or even working) link should just be flagged as non-answers.

Comment: What do you mean by `poke the user` ? I [can't PM](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/instant-messaging-on-so-sf-su) someone on SO

Comment: @Tim Post: Absolutely.

Comment: @pinouchon: I meant poking via a comment.

Comment: and if there is no way to fix it? Suppose, the user posts an image they create to imgur and the image is now broken?

Comment: @SpaceDog Poke the user about it. If the answer can't stand without the image, flagging it might be an option. But keep in mind that I've been out of the loop for a few years now, so there might be a different protocol by now. But if the answer can't stand without the (now defunct) image, it's not an answer anymore and should be removed.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby - ok thanks, but suppose the answer can stand without the image, should I remove the link or flag?

Comment: @SpaceDog If the answer can't stand without the image (and you or the user can't provide it), then it is not an answer anymore.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby, sorry but my question was not that. My question was, what to do with the link when the answer CAN stand without it. Thanks and sorry bothering you that much.

Comment: @SpaceDog Mistake on my end, I parsed your question wrongly. Anyway, if it can stand without the image, then edit the image out. It's a "nice to have" but not essential, as long as it is there, it is nice to have, but it can do without it. As said, ping the user about it, remove it, move on in that case.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby - ah, thanks for your answer. You are awesome! 

Answer (score 1):

Could SE encourage link-providing users to also provide an additional link to an archive, e.g., [archive.org](https://archive.org/)? That's what Wikipedia does with its [`cite web` template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Cite_web#Using_.22archive-url.22_and_.22archive-date.22_.28and_optionally_.22dead-url.22.29_for_webpages_that_have_been_archived). `archive.org` also makes "saving" (i.e., archiving a previously unarchived page) easy, which reinforces the habit.